Phase transition and connection with fluid dynamics
In statistical mechanics, when there’s a phase transition, is there a mechanism that actually enforces it? For example, could there be some specific motion of the particles that forces a phase transition, instead of just an increase in temperature? Of course, I know there’s a connection between particle motion and temperature.
But I’ve noticed a very interesting phenomenon in three-dimensional flows, and I’m trying to see if there’s an analogy. In short, it appears that the increase in temperature (or the change in the parameters governing the flow) is a consequence of the motion, rather than the cause.
I’ve basically noticed that in the dynamics, there is likely a natural flow over the parameter space defined according to the system’s cycles, which is why I’m asking. Or to phrase it in physical terms:
Suppose we have a dynamical system that depends on some parameter. Then the parameter itself must change during the motion—in other words, the laws of motion naturally change as the system evolves. This implies that there is a natural dynamical system defined on the space of dynamical systems, which itself serves as the rule of motion. In practice, this might make the motion appear to have a stochastic element, but it isn’t truly stochastic. It’s simply that the laws of motion change over time.
The definition of this law is derived from extending the flow into the parameter space, incorporating the Yorke orbit index, which defines the invariant manifolds of this motion. These invariant manifolds dictate the movement.
This forms a dynamical system defined on both the phase space and the parameter space. According to Yorke’s results, it likely holds in any parameter space and could cause things to appear as though there is stochastic noise. I have an idea to attempt to use this in constructing a mathematical model of the dynamics of the Great Ocean Conveyor Belt.
At the moment, this is still in the planning stage, but it’s quite clear to me that this approach defines such a concept and seems, at least intuitively, to explain certain bifurcation behavior.

It is hard to give an answer without knowing more about the hydrodynamic phenomena mentioned in the Q... However, I dare suggest that the question arose from misunderstanding of what phase transitions are.
More specifically:

In statistical mechanics, when there’s a phase transition, is there a mechanism that actually enforces it? For example, could there be some specific motion of the particles that forces a phase transition, instead of just an increase in temperature? Of course, I know there’s a connection between particle motion and temperature.

(emphasis is mine)
Phase transitions are not dynamic processes which take place when we change temperature (in other words, they are not really transitions in time.) Rather, we compare systems in equilibrium at different temperatures (and values of other parameters) and note that the parameter space is split into regions, where the equilibrium state of the system has very different structure: e.g., it can be a solid, a gas or a liquid; or the system may be paramagnetic or ferromagnetic - see Phase diagram. Dynamics of phase transitions, that is how the system transforms in time when we change temperature or other parameters is of substantial interest, and appears to be a rather difficult problem in its own right, and as far as I know, not much is known about it yet (at least, not on the textbook level.)
The fluid dynamic phenomenon described in the Q. seems more related to the domain of nonlinear dynamics, where the structure of motion changes when the parameters are change - see Bifurcation theory. Again, what is of interest here is not the process of changing the parameters, but different types of motion that exist in the phase space, at different parameter combinations. But at least this actually deals with motion, rather than a thermodynamic equilibrium.
Finally, since fluid dynamics is described by equations that are not linear, non-linear phenomena in fluid dynamics are quite common see, e.g., Rayleigh–Bénard convection, Reaction-diffusion system, Dissipative soliton, and Swift-Hohenberg equation (the last article contains very little information, but the equation serves as a model equation for a multitude of nonlinear phenomena and therefore is worth mentioning as a search keyword.)
